# How to grep a line start with "*" using grep

Tags: command-line, grep, regex, syntax

How can I use 'grep' to get lines start with '* ' in my file?

I tried  `grep "*" myfile` and `grep "* " myfile` but returns all the lines of my file.

Answer (score 11):

The "*" is a special character that means "0 or more of the previous character."  You need to escape this character.

```
grep '^\*' myfile
```